# slider / input updating another slider / input for loan calculator

Tags: jquery, input, slider, range, calculator

I'm doing a loan calculator for real estate.
I try to update each sliders (Range) and inputs (text) to have my result without a button (instantly).
I started my code for loan amount and term.If loan amount changes, term must do it also.

My problem :

When i move slider of loan amount, input text of loan amount and term are updated BUT not the slider of the term.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mensualite_slider').on('input', function(){
    $('#mensualite').val($('#mensualite_slider').val());
});
$('#mensualite').on('input', function(){
    $('#mensualite_slider').val($('#mensualite').val());
});
$('#capital_slider').on('input', function(){
    $('#capital').val($('#capital_slider').val());
    $('#mensualite').on('input', function(){
    $('#mensualite_slider').val($('#mensualite').val());
    });
    ma_fonction();
});
$('#capital').on('input', function(){
    $('#capital_slider').val($('#capital').val());
});
});
</script>
```

My code is in french !
mensualité = term.
capital = loan amount.

thx !

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, i put an event in the function.Now it works !!